# $u,1/u$ are solutions to $(p(x)y')'+q(x)y=0$, show $u$ solves a first-order diff equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling with this question: we have two differentiable functions $p, q$ in some interval $I$ and the equation $(p(x)y')'+q(x)y=0$, with given solutions $u$ and $1/u$. We're asked to show $u$ solves a first-order differential equation.

**What I tried:** I tried two things: plugging the solutions to the equation and differentiating, and plugging the solutions and integrating (to get rid of the 2nd order derivative). It didn't get me very far, though ...

Comment: What is $u$ here?

Comment: [Abel's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) should help you out.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: It's a function $u(x)$ that solves the equation

Comment: @user12477: Thanks, but I think the solution is meant to be more elementary (we haven't learned much at all about 2nd order equations yet)!

Comment: ...I think you were on the right track in the first place. Since $u$ and $u^{-1}$ are both solutions, we have two separate equations involving $u''$. Eliminating $u''$ from these leaves an equation involving just $u$ and $u'$ (and coefficients depending on $p,p',q$) - in other words exactly what you've been asked to find! You don't need to integrate.

Comment: Yup, I made a calculation error which made me think it was the wrong approach. Oh well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know
$$
\left(p u'\right)' + qu = p u'' + p' u' + qu = 0
$$
and
$$
\left[p \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)'\right]' + \frac{q}{u} = \frac{2 p u'^2}{u^3} + \frac{p u''}{u^2} - \frac{p' u'}{u^2}+\frac{q}{u} = 0.
$$
Multiply the second equation by $u^2$:
$$
\frac{2 p u'^2}{u} + p u'' - p' u' + q u = 0.
$$
Subtract this equation from the first equation:
$$
2 p' u' - \frac{2 p u'^2}{u} = 0.
$$

Comment: Ugh. This is exactly what I did, but I made a calculation error which made me think it wouldn't work.